# When running Robotium test, how can I close the low battery dialog?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Problem and scenario:

I am running battery rundown test for my Android device. It test the device while looping flash pages in the Browser.apk. To automate the testing I used Robotium.
However when the battery goes to 15%, the low battery dialog appears so the Robotium test stops. Do you have any idea to fix my problem? I appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either try to keep the charger connected.
Or do not use robotium, I would suggest use UIAutomator.
It is more less like robotium, but unlike robotium it can navigate outside its package and handle activites.